# Link socket.io ID with express and passport

Tags: express, socket.io, passport.js

The goal of my simple try is to display online user list.  I mean display not socket.io ID but display user profile. When authorized user connects to my server, open socket.io channel, it is required to get his profile and send message to other connected user that new user (Name, email, etc) has being connected. I saw many examples how to do it within authorization, but it doesn't handle a disconnect. What i want to do and what i can't do in pseudocode:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
io.set("authorization", function(data, callback){
     // ... some code...
     callback(null, true);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var UserProfile = passport.getUserProfile(socket.id) 
    io.sockets.emit('user_connected', {UserProfile: UserProfile, socketID: socket.id}); 

    io.sockets.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
         io.sockets.emit('user_disconnected', {socketID: socket.id});
    }); 

});
```

*This is a pseudocode!*
My stack is overflowed. I just want to link socket.io ID and passport account together within connection. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and my solution is the following (hopefully someone gets a better idea):

- i add the username to the render call (using jade):
  res.render('chatroom', {username: req.user.username});
- right after connecting to socket on the client (io.connect), i emit a
  message to the server, with the username as parameter, using the connect event on the client (socket.on('connect', function (data) { ... });
- on the server, i store the username in an object (clients[socket.id]
  = username)
- after that, i get the username in every socket message by accessing
  the clients object

Comment: great answer @luschn...quick question what is this line of code effectively doing
clients[socket.id] = username
Is it assigning a property to an object using bracket notation?

Comment: yeah, you cannot use dot notation in this case (clients.socket.id would be something completely different). basically it takes the socket id as key in an associative array/object and uses the username as value.